# Query Date Ranges Within a Range but special case

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, range

I'm really struggling to logically think of things with date ranges.

For example:

If **Event A** is the 9th - 15th and then the user searches 10th - 13th then at the moment I’ve got it returning all the events that start from the 10th until the 13th as that is what the user searched.

But because **Event A** is from the 9th - 15th it won't show on that search but I would like it to show because it's still within the range of the 9th - 15th.

I hope that makes sense.

Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Can you share some table-structure and the query you are currently using? Preferably create a DB fiddle.

Comment: What operation are you using to capture the range? and in where?

Comment: @Qirel just updated the post with the db layout mate.

Comment: @tcadidot0 I'm use WP_Query but haven't written this part yet but I was thinking to use the BETWEEN comparison but wasn't too sure if that would work,

Comment: could this help? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/34888/how-do-i-search-events-between-two-set-dates-inside-wp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wpquery in an array :

```
 'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => $metaKey,
            // value should be array of (lower, higher) with BETWEEN
            'value' => array('START_DATE', 'END_DATE'),
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
            'type' => 'DATE'
        ),
    )
```

here is a real world example in mysql and php:

```
 $db = getDB();
                $sql = "SELECT
                              DATE(invoice_date) AS invoice_date,
                              COUNT(sage_allsalesbyproduct.id) AS row_count,
                              SUM(sage_allsalesbyproduct.qty) AS total_qty,
                              SUM(sage_allsalesbyproduct.gross) AS total_gross,
                              sage_allsalesbyproduct.productcode,
                              ItemGroup as item_group
                            FROM sage_allsalesbyproduct
                            left join stock s on s.ProductCode = sage_allsalesbyproduct.productcode
                            WHERE
                              invoice_date BETWEEN :fromdate AND :todate
                            GROUP BY productcode
                            order by total_qty desc";
                $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->bindParam("fromdate", $fromdate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->bindParam("todate", $todate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->execute();
                $feedData = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                $db = null;
                echo json_encode($feedData);
```

**remember MySQL uses yyyy-mm-dd format for storing a date value. This format is fixed and it is not possible to change it.**

With mysql you can also do something like

```
SELECT *
FROM order_details
WHERE order_date >= CAST('2014-02-01' AS DATE)
AND order_date <= CAST('2014-02-28' AS DATE);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar table and usually do something like the following to get all the results:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `events` 
WHERE ('2019-07-10' BETWEEN `start_date` AND `end_date`
   OR '2019-07-13'  BETWEEN `start_date` AND `end_date`);
```

Answer (score 1):

The logic for overlaps is that two time spans overlap when both begin before the other ends.

This is easy to implement as:

```
select e.*
from e
where e.start_date < $end_date and
      $start_date < e.end_date;
```

If the `end_date` is included in the range, then use `<=` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM `events` as e
WHERE (  e.date_start BETWEEN [INPUT datestart] AND  [INPUT dateend]
     OR   e.date_end  BETWEEN [INPUT datestart] AND  [INPUT dateend]
    )
;
```

This will show up possible overlap of dates.

Comment: Thanks mate. Do you know how I would write that as a WP META Query?